# Error when installing brms package in R - bayesplot cannot be installed

Tags: r

I am trying to install the R package `brms` on  my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS computer. My R version is 4.2.2 and I am using RStudio RStudio 2022.07.2 "Spotted Wakerobin".

`rstan` is installed and I have successfully verified the installation. My stan version is 2.21.0.

When I try installing `brms` in RStudio this is the output:

```
> install.packages("brms")
Installing package into ‘/home/iplank/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘bayesplot’, ‘shinystan’, ‘bridgesampling’, ‘nleqslv’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/bayesplot_1.10.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4993447 bytes (4.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/shinystan_2.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2399890 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/bridgesampling_1.1-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1679600 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/nleqslv_3.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 84686 bytes (82 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 82 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/brms_2.18.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4486548 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘bayesplot’ ...
** package ‘bayesplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in element_line(linewidth = 0.3) : 
  unused argument (linewidth = 0.3)
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘bayesplot’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘bayesplot’
* removing ‘/home/iplank/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/bayesplot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bayesplot’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘bridgesampling’ ...
** package ‘bridgesampling’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (bridgesampling)
* installing *source* package ‘nleqslv’ ...
** package ‘nleqslv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/BH/include" -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/home/iplank/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/usr/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1      -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-Faorqz/r-base-4.2.2.20221110=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c init.c -o init.o
In file included from /usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:88,
                 from /usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /usr/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      |                 ^
In file included from /usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /usr/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:96:10: fatal error: complex: No such file or directory
   96 | #include <complex>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:169: init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nleqslv’
* removing ‘/home/iplank/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/nleqslv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nleqslv’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘bayesplot’ is not available for package ‘shinystan’
* removing ‘/home/iplank/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/shinystan’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shinystan’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘bayesplot’, ‘shinystan’, ‘nleqslv’ are not available for package ‘brms’
* removing ‘/home/iplank/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/brms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpS56F1Q/downloaded_packages’
```

There seems to be a problem when installing `bayesplot` but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and installing the development version no longer works. Now, you need to specify version `1.9.0` to install `bayesplot`:

```
library(remotes)
install_version("bayesplot", version = "1.9.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Information on this bug can be found at the following github issue:
https://github.com/stan-dev/bayesplot/issues/297

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someon encounters the same problem:

I installed `devtools` to be able to install `bayesplot` directly from github using:

```
install_github("stan-dev/bayesplot", dependencies = TRUE, build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

This only worked for me after installing all the packages that throw compilation errors in R directly and **not** in RStudio.

After `bayesplot` was installed, I was able to install `brms`.